# Read JSON from Server (Java)

Tags: java, android, json

First of all, sorry for this silly question.

Can anyone help me out with the code about how to read this JSON file from server? I have messed up my java code after watching several tutorials.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Coleen Sanford",
    "location": {
      "latitude": -60.489023,
      "longitude": -32.311668
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Bethany Church",
    "location": {
      "latitude": -1.304805,
      "longitude": -80.670287
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Kristy Ware",
    "location": {
      "latitude": -46.443562,
      "longitude": -46.426997
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Avery Navarro",
    "location": {
      "latitude": 35.719469,
      "longitude": -172.783006
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Robyn Cruz",
    "location": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Vinson Hays",
    "location": null
  }
]
```

**This is my code:**

```
/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray  contacts = new JSONArray (jsonStr);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = c.getString("name");

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("location");
                    String latitude = phone.getString("latitude");
                    String longitude = phone.getString("longitude");

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("name", name);
                    contact.put("latitude", latitude);
                    contact.put("longitude", longitude);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "latitude",
                "longitude"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                R.id.latitude, R.id.longitude});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}}
```

Comment: use `optString` 'cuz some values are null plus `jsonStr` is jsonarray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) Which is a google powerd tool for serializing and de-serializing Json

Then add the gson dependency to your code,

```
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

Next thing you want to do is to create some sample model classes to serialize your json data, use this [link](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com) and paste your json data and create corresponding classes

Then is the java code, (Lets say your base model class name is **UserLocation**

> Userlocation

```
    public class UserLocation{
        private Location location;

        private String name;

        public Location getLocation ()
        {
            return location;
        }

        public void setLocation (Location location)
        {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public String getName ()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName (String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
  }
```

> Location

```
    public class Location {
    private double longitude;

    private double latitude;

    public double getLongitude ()
    {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude (double longitude)
    {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude ()
    {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude (double latitude)
    {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
}
```

in code

```
List<UserLocation> userLocationList = Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(yourResponseString, UserLocation[].class));
```

This is it, everything will be under this **userLocationList**

Happy coding.. :)

Comment: check the pojo class again and json response

Comment: edited your answer and let me tell in short, latitude and longitude are of double type in json response not of string  type

Comment: well no offense, but the Gson converter takes string also will prevent from crashing and agree the fact the its double, but as i said am just providing a sample class. it can be converted as wanted by the user, Cheers @quicklearner

Comment: yes , gson is better , does not give null pointer exception when the object is null and thats okay , we all are learning, Enjoy Coding

Comment: Exactly my thought. Don't waste time doing primitive deserialization. Use Gson or JAXB.

Answer (score 1):

Try that in your AsyncTask for download json file. This method returned String with json.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic that_my_Basic_Auth");
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        resultJson = buffer.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultJson;
}
```

Then you can get JSONObject like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new MyAsyncTask().execute(string_url).get());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
You should get contact array correctly and also Latitude and Longitude which is a double type

```
 if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            // Getting JSON Array node
            JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray ();
            contacts=jsonObj.getJSONArray("keyforarray")
            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = c.getString("name");
                // Phone node is JSON Object
                JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("location");
                double latitude = phone.getDouble("latitude");
                double longitude = phone.getDouble("longitude");
                // tmp hash map for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put("name", name);
                contact.put("latitude", String.valueOf(latitude));
                contact.put("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
                // adding contact to contact list
                contactList.add(contact);
            }
        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }
    }
```